# Multiple Post request with different parameter Retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

I have something like this in the interface

```
    @POST("login")
    Call<LoginResponse> Login(@Query("email") String email, 
                              @Query("password") String password);
```

I want to make the first parameter's name to become either `email` or `user_name` according to whether typed in the `editText` is email or username
 How  I can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@QueryMap` for this purpose

```
@POST("login")
Call<LoginResponse> Login(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

And use it like this

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("email", "mail@example.com"); //change email to user_name when you need
data.put("password", "secret");

...
...

loginService.Login(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much That's work too. although it's a dynamic request which is better for me

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a separate service/function if they enter a user_name? I.e.

```
@POST("login")
Call<LoginResponse> LoginByUsername(@Query("user_name") String userName, 
                          @Query("password") String password);
```